# Why async service dont fill check-box form panel?

Tags: java, checkbox, gwt, gxt, gwt-rpc

I am developing an GWT app and when user clicks on button, form panel with checkboxes should appear. Those checkboxes should be filled with list of items from async service. But when I open form panel I dont have those checkboxes. I debugged and saw that result from my service is not here on time, but later list is full.. 
Here is the code:

```
     @Override
        public void createBody() {


            GWT_ACCESS_ROLE_SERVICE.findByUserId(null, currentSession.getSelectedAccount().getId(), userId, new AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>>() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole> result) {
                  lista   = result.getData();
                    for (GwtAccessRole gwtAccessRole : lista) {
                     bb = new CheckBox();
                        bb.setBoxLabel(gwtAccessRole.getRoleName());
                    }
                    FormPanel roleFormPanel = new FormPanel(FORM_LABEL_WIDTH);
                    roleFormPanel.add(bb);

                    bodyPanel.add(roleFormPanel);

                }
            });

        }
```

What am I doing wrong and why my checkboxes are not filled? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: When I debug, this method GWT_ACCESS_ROLE_SERVICE.findByUserId is shown AFTER Form Panel appears. So Form Panel apperas and after that debug goes to this my method and does all the stuff.

Comment: You say checkboxes but I only see one checkbox being created.

Comment: I changed it, I moved bb = new CheckBox() into foreach but again the same..

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this then:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("LOG OUTPUT");

@Override
public void onSuccess(PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole> result) {

    if (result == null) {
        log.info("No data from the server");
        return;
    }

    lista   = result.getData();

    FormPanel roleFormPanel = new FormPanel(FORM_LABEL_WIDTH);

    for (GwtAccessRole gwtAccessRole : lista) {
        bb = new CheckBox();
        bb.setBoxLabel(gwtAccessRole.getRoleName());
        roleFormPanel.add(bb);

        // display on the JS console output
        log.info("CheckBox added to roleFormPanel");
    }

    bodyPanel.add(roleFormPanel);

    // confirm panel being added
    log.info("Panel added to body");
}
```

.gwt.xml module will have these lines added:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
```

You were not adding anything to the form panel as the checkbox had gone out of scope.

EDIT: added logging output information

Comment: I generally use `SimpleCheckBox` instead of `CheckBox`. Also check that your form panel is being added to the body using the inspector in Chrome or Firefox. Add some debugging output to ensure it is reaching that particular piece of code too.

Comment: I will try it now.

Comment: Updated code in answer. Hopefully the logging will be able to get you somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it is an ASynchronous RPC call which returns to onFailure or onSuccess only when the server has finished doing its processing. 99% of GWT is run by events and server calls are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Note that **FormPanel** is implement **HasOneWidget**, so if you try to put one more widget to container it will override it